# Use regionprops to get table with label and area

Tags: matlab, region, contourf

So i have this plicture that i made from a microscopic image of a composite sample. Basically what I did is that i have an array A that contains the value of an angle Phi from -90 to +90 degrees. and then I used contourf to get this plot:
[image]

Now I want to label each region with a number and get a table with the area in pixel of each. I am trying to use the function regionprops in this way:
A is my array of data

```
angs = -90:10:90;

for i = 1:numel(angs)-1

    BW = A>=angs(i) & A<angs(i+1);

    R{i} = regionprops(BW, 'Area');

end
```

I get an solution like this:

```
R = 

  Columns 1 through 3

    [32x1 struct]    [450x1 struct]    [1110x1 struct]

  Columns 4 through 6

    [1978x1 struct]    [2778x1 struct]    [3392x1 struct]

  Columns 7 through 9

    [5249x1 struct]    [8215x1 struct]    [15711x1 struct]

  Columns 10 through 12

    [12019x1 struct]    [5335x1 struct]    [2643x1 struct]

  Columns 13 through 15

    [1804x1 struct]    [1018x1 struct]    [670x1 struct]

  Columns 16 through 18

    [579x1 struct]    [344x1 struct]    [50x1 struct]
```

But I want to display a table and I want to know which region is which on the picture. 
Do you have any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Will try to post more details later, in the meantime have a look at http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2014/02/04/regionprops-tables-and-struct2table/

Comment: I looked at it but i am still a bit lost, do you have more suggestions ?